# How to provide INSPIRE metadata from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, inspire

AFAIU the GeoServer INSPIRE extension adds some stuff to the extended capabilities document that provides the URL to the metadata.

But is there any way that the INSPIRE-compliant metadata file can be compiled by GeoServer?

Comment: You are looking for GeoNetwork

Comment: MapServer will do it. You can specify type one or type  two extended metadata section, and also MapServer will compile ISO metadata from your configuration and add it to the metadataURL automatically unless you specify another metadataURL

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make a service INSPIRE compliant:

- Include the metadata in the capabilities document
- Link from the capabilities document to an external resource providing the metadata

The Geoserver INSPIRE extension module allows to implement the second option, there is no support for the first (could be implemented, if you are interested in coding it, go on the developer list and ask for directions, if you want to sponsor it, check the commercial support page at geoserver.org).